# Is There a Unique Record Key for Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple admin I'm creating for a client using PHP and Mysql.  Anytime I wish to edit or delete a record I have to send the table name and unique index of my record(an auto incremented field I call index) in my query.  This is fine except passing around a table parameter seems like it would be redundant if Msyql generates it's own unique index for EACH record in a particular database.

Anyone know if there is such a thing?

THE REASONING:

I'm making an admin table with (for this example) two columns.  One column has a title, the other has a delete button.  To build this table I query a table called inventory:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `inventory`";
$results = mysql_query($query);
$table = 'inventory';
$returnString = '
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Command</th>
        </tr>
    ';

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
    $returnString .='
        <tr>
            <td>' . $data['title'] . '</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="delete" onclick="remove_record(' . $data['index']. ',\'' . $data['table'] . '\')" />
        </tr>';
}

$returnString .='</table>';

return $returnString;
```

So, it's fine. It works fine except that I'd be happy NOT sending around two pieces of data (the index AND table name) through my javascript function, back through my formhandler back through my query to retrieve a piece of data I GENERATED FROM an original query.

It would be GREAT if there was some sort of GLOBAL reference to a record so I could create a function that would just eliminate a record from ANYWHERE in my database.

Comment: [Auto Increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html). Is this not unique enough ?

Comment: @Khez, it's unique to THAT table.  I'm curious if there is some sort of GLOBAL index I have access to.

Comment: Why would you need an ID shared across tables?

Comment: You will still have to include the table name in your SQL statements anyway, just by necessity of the SQL syntax. You'd have to go [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL_(concept)) to get rid of that.

Comment: @ceejayoz.  Because in order to come back and edit that record I have to pass a parameter with the table id three times.  Once to the form I proved the administrator, then once from the form to my form handler, and then once in the final query.  I'd like to eliminate passing around that parameter with some sort of global ID Wherein I could write a query as simple as "DELETE GLOBAL_ID"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, MySQL doesn't create an expicit unique id (e.g. a global guid) for every record created in the database. I also don't think it makes *sense* for it to exist, since this job is already fulfilled by creating primary keys in each table.

The combination of the table name and that table's primary key *are* the unique value for the record since no other record in the database can hold that primary key for that table.

I'm at a loss to comprehend the reasoning behind this question. If you need to store a reference to a specific record in a separate table, then you should be adding a foreign key constraint on that other table to reference the primary key of the first table.

Comment: I'll tell you exactly why I want to avoid this.  Instead of passing around a table id AND index to my form, then my javascript function then my form handler and finally my query I could write something as simple as "DELETE GLOBAL_ID"

Comment: @Jascha Since that's an [invalid SQL statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html) it wouldn't make much difference if there *was* such a thing as a global id.

Comment: @Jascha I'm don't understand the design decisions that would lead to needing such a construct. Table+PrimaryKey *is* the unique value. If you have to pass this around a lot, then what's the difference between a global record guid and an array containing the table and id? I still think there's got to be a better way to do this than your idea, but without specifics on your problem I can't help you.

Comment: @agentConundrum, I think my intent is pretty obvious.  I'm looking to take one step out of the process.  I see no problem with that design decision.  If I'm combining two bits of information (table+key) I still have to split them at one point.  It's twice as much work.  This is why I'm asking.

Comment: @Jascha Still, I don't think it's possible to do what you're asking. Databases already have a way to identify unique records - the primary key - so that's what we use. Sorry.

Comment: @agentconundrum, that's all I wanted to know :)  Thank you for your responses.